# Go Lang to check io.Writer type

Tags: go, types

simple question.
I dont understand one thing.

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    records := [][]string{
        {"first_name", "last_name", "username"},
        {"Rob", "Pike", "rob"},
        {"Ken", "Thompson", "ken"},
        {"Robert", "Griesemer", "gri"},
    }

    file, _ := os.Create("file.csv")

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(file))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(os.Stdout))

    w := csv.NewWriter(file)

    for _, record := range records {
        if err := w.Write(record); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("error writing record to csv:", err)
        }
    }

    // Write any buffered data to the underlying writer (standard output).
    w.Flush()

    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Line : `w := csv.NewWriter(file)` I checked method -> `NewWriter` should get paramter with `io.Writer` type. Line 21 and 22 told me that "file" and "os.Stdout" (which can be put into NewWriter too) have these types :
*os.File
*os.File
So how is that possible everything is working properly? Is that possible in Go that variables has more than one type?

Comment: [io.Writer](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) is an interface.  Read about interfaces in [the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) and [the Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.Create` returns `*os.File` [1], as you said.

`io.Writer` is an interface. That means, any types that implement the interface,
can act as the interface. In this case, the type only need to implement a `Write`
function [2].

Since `os.File` does implement a `Write` function [3], it can be used anywhere
a `io.Writer` is required.

1. https://golang.org/pkg/os#Create
2. https://golang.org/pkg/io#Writer
3. https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.Write